# Any way to make use of ImageClassificationInstance in C#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I keep getting `Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented" ...` exception when I try to use the `ImageClassificationInstance` objects to classify using a model I have created in the Vertex AI. Is there any way (either by using Google AiPlatform library or using `HttpRequest` ) to perform ImageClassification with some given image?

The following is the code that I am using

```cs
        var client = builder.Build();
        var instance = new ImageClassificationPredictionInstance() { Content = rawdata };
        var parameters = new ImageClassificationPredictionParams() { ConfidenceThreshold = 0.5f, MaxPredictions = 5 };
        var pv = ValueConverter.ToValue(parameters);
        var iv = new[] { ValueConverter.ToValue(instance) };
        var ep = new EndpointName("My project ID", "us-central1", "My endpoint id"); // Of course I have set the string to my project ID and my endpoint ID
        var returnobj = client.Predict(ep, iv, pv); // This is where the exception pops up
```

I can confirm that my vertex AI AutoML model is working on the web browser to classify any uploaded picture.

Comment: You can check [Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest) NuGet package for your requirement. For sample codes, you can check Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1 NuGet Package in [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar On checking the source code of both the packages [`Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/PredictionServiceClient.g.cs) and [`Google.Cloud.AIPlatform`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/PredictionServiceClient.g.cs) All `Predict()` methods throw a `NotImplementedException` (or a similar exception) believe this library cannot be used to make a prediction Can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: Hi @AzuxirenLeadGuy, although they throw NotImplementedException (or a similar exception) , they can be used for prediction. For more information you can check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest). Can you please try to implement this and check ? Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must set Endpoint on PredictionServiceClientBuilder :

```
var client = new PredictionServiceClientBuilder
        {
            Endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
        }.Build();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response but I was using the services in trial mode and now it is expired so I can't confirm right away if it works in order to accept your answer